# any() in python coding issue

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that tells you if a number is prime or not using the any() method. This is what I have:

```
def prime(n):
    if any(n % i == 0 for i in range(1, n + 1)) != True:
        print("Prime")
    else:
        print("Not Prime")

prime(5)
```

However it is giving me:

```
Not Prime
```

every single time, even when I give a prime number.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: As an aside from the answer already given, note that for any boolean `b`, `if b != True` would be written more idiomatically as `if not b`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is divisible by 1, so that check will consider everything as non-prime. You need to set the lower bound to check to 2 instead.

As pointed out in the comments by @ForceBru, the upper bound is incorrect as well. You don't want to check if `n` is divisible by itself, since it always will be.

Change your `range` in the comprehension to just:

```
range(2, n))
```

Comment: Also, `n % n == 0` as well.

Comment: Then again why not put a `not` in front of the `any` and remove the `!= True`. It would make things clearer.

Comment: To significantly speed up the test for larger numbers you should stop checking above the square root of `n`.

Comment: All good points, but they kind of detract from the main problem.